# Table view in action sheet in xamarin ios

Tags: uitableview, xamarin, xamarin.ios, uiactionsheet

How we can add a table view in the action sheet. am using xamarin ios. I need an action sheet with a table view which has an accordion. I can do normal table view with accordion. I need the table view inside the action sheet

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you should do is to use [UIAlertController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uialertcontroller) instead of the [UIActionSheet](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiactionsheet), which was deprecated in iOS 8. You'll have a more future proof app with an easier to work with alert functionality.

`UIAlertController` inherits from [UIViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller) which let's you add subviews as you desire.

```
// Create a new UIAlertController
var alertController = UIAlertController.Create("Alert Title", "Some text here", UIAlertControllerStyle.ActionSheet);

// Add your custom view to the alert. Any UIView can be added.
var yourTableView = new UITableView();
alertController.View.AddSubview(yourTableView)

// Add Actions
alertController.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create("Ok", UIAlertActionStyle.Default, alert => Console.WriteLine ("Ok clicked")));
alertController.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create("Cancel", UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, alert => Console.WriteLine ("Cancel clicked")));

// Show the alert
controller.PresentViewController(alertController, true, null);
```

[Here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32790207/uialertcontroller-add-custom-views-to-actionsheet) of this in action, although it's in Swift.