# Cancel Button is not tappable in custom action sheet

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

Refer to link [UIAlertController - add custom views to actionsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32790207/uialertcontroller-add-custom-views-to-actionsheet#) 
for my UI layout.

I have the same layout of custom action sheet in my app. The code is written in the same way. I noticed that in swift4 the "Cancel" button does not perform any action. When I tap on "Cancel" button in code below

```
let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: {(alert: UIAlertAction!) in 
     print("Cancel")
})
```

The code: `print(Cancel")` does not execute.

Comment: It does not print Cancel ?

Comment: it will works perfectly for me

Comment: Did you added this action to the Controller?

Comment: post full code how you are adding the custom view to alert controller . The same code mentioned in the post works like charm

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a problem with a frame of the custom view.
Run you application on a simulator and press "Debug View Hierarchy":
[image]
After that you'll can exam frames of views.

Answer (score 0):

Try this handler

```
UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: { (action) -> Void in
            print("cancel")
        }))
```