# Can an action sheet or alert have interactive elements?

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview, uiactionsheet, uialertaction

Is there a way for an action sheet alert to have anything dynamic and interactive.  From everything I have read I can only find cocoa pod installs of customizations or the ability add buttons that do something.  I haven't found any way to add things like an image to header, a text field a user can type in,  or a picker view for input.

I have a simple app that has an array of dates, around 20. I want the user to tap a UIButton (which has the currently selected date as the button text) and then have a picker view appear as an alert where they can pick a different date.

I am new to swift, is this just something so complex that I need a cocoa pod customization?  I was thinking of just faking it out myself by programatically dropping in a text label over the whole screen to disable it and then show and hide the picker view myself.  I suspect that would be a nube way of brute forcing that though.

-dan

Comment: you can add xibs in action sheet

Comment: Hope this help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32790207/uialertcontroller-add-custom-views-to-actionsheet

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can add interactive elements these controllers have a center view please refer below git repo which i find very useful:https://github.com/dillidon/alerts-and-pickers