# iOS 13 emojis are in gray color showing

Tags: swift, ios13, xcode11, xcode10, ios12

In ios12 emojis are showing perfect but I updated my Xcode and in iOS 13 all emojis turns to gray any one please help me how can be able to fix this.

In code I have written like this 
     //Show pop up

```
let otherAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Souhaites-tu supprimer cette notification ?", message: "", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.actionSheet)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56955800/793607 also attempts to answer this.

Comment: Also, its interesting that alert style alertController's still show them in color.

Comment: @HalR I see the answers suggested by you but don't find any solutions there. Does UIAlerViewController do no longer support emoji in colourful in ios13. Please suggest.

Comment: UIAlertViewController in .action mode does not support color emoji in ios13.  The link I posted shows someone making a custom class to use instead.