# Action sheet show from .XIB file in Swift 5

Tags: uitabbarcontroller, xib, swift5, actionsheet

I have a question regarding loading XIB file to the action sheet inside UITabBar Controller.

I would like to show signIn method with Google, Facebook, and email inside an action sheet.

Trying to use this code but the style of the button and text not showing properly.  Do you guys have any example of showing xib file or any custom view to the action sheet in TabController?

```
let myView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("SignInView", owner: nil)![0] as! UIView

@IBAction func showSignIn() {
        let actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: "\n\n\n\n\n\n", message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

        actionSheet.view.addSubview(myView)
        present(actionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Thank you!

Comment: Can you please share photos what you exactly want ?

Comment: I think your question has an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32790207/uialertcontroller-add-custom-views-to-actionsheet)